# File output of an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, io

Writing a program that reads in data from .dat file for analysis. The data was not spaced so used fgets to take the cluttered data and save into variables. The integers and floats work fine, but the char strings won't output.

```
 fgets(tempfile, 8, DataFile);
 strcpy(date_3[i], tempfile);
```

The data reads in fine and is stored in a global variable

```
char date_3[33100][7];
```

[Screenshot of data stored in i=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RG62.jpg)

I'm preparing some of the output of the analysis including this array of strings.
I tried

```
FILE *Output;                                               
    Output = fopen("file", "w");    
    int i = 0;                                                   
    for (i = 0; i < profile_count; i++)                         
    {
        fprintf(Output," %7s \n",date_3[i]);
    }
    fclose(Output);
```

Even compiling this without the for loop

```
fprintf(Output," %7s \n", date_3[0]);
```

outputs the entire array.

Overall, want it to print " 1FEB73"

Comment: If it outputs the whole array, you probably don't have a string-terminating NUL character in the right location. Try creating a temporary buffer and copying however-many characters into that area, then appending a `'\0'`.

Comment: @AustinHastings

On the money. Was able to resolve it by simply changing the variable  to
char date[33100][8]

Comment: @AustinHastings: Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Lost_in_the_sauce it is entirely unclear what you are dealing with in the `.dat` file (`.dat` generally denoting a binary file). If your problem is solved, that's fine, if not, post a snippet from your data file (if not binary, a link if it is). If you are attempting to read a binary file with `fgets`, that won't work as there are no newlines and any data you get back will either be the full contents of your buffer or a partial based on encountering a stray value of `0xa`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin

`3AUG7312  75  75222.033.010IC .030117.022.010AC .1401 2.017.0 5CB .400210.016.0 1LS .2002 0.010.0 1RN .040 `

Unsure of what exported the data to this file as it is older than me. The problem is resolved and `fgets` worked so long as I allowed an extra space for the `\n`

Comment: If you can read it from the console or in a text editor, then it is just plain text (ASCII), so that answers the question. Looks like your found the problem in not providing sufficient space for the string. You can always determine if the line was longer than the space you provided by checking for the presence of a `'\n'` in the text read by `fgets` (e.g. `if (!strchr (buf, '\n'))` a short-read occurred and more text remains in that line to be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it outputs the whole array, you probably don't have a string-terminating NUL character in the right location. Try creating a temporary buffer and copying however-many characters into that area, then appending a `'\0'`.